# Automating visual tasks

Tags: command-line, python, automation, ncmpcpp

How can I automate task's which need a display to run , eg: ncmpcpp . I am using python to do this but the error is as follows `Error opening terminal: unknown.\r`. Is there any other means I can do it ? I am using a module called pexpect in python to do this. And I don't want the terminal window to open . An eg of the automation can be that, ncmpcc opens its playlist which is done by pressing 2 and then getting the result as stoud or a log file.

As I am using python to do it. I am using a module called `pexpect` to do it.
The code is pretty simple .

```
import pexpect

child = pexpect.spawn("ncmpcpp")
# time.sleep(2)
# child.sendline("q")
print(child.read())
```

But when I run the error comes

Comment: @Nmath I updated the question

Comment: It is still unclear.  You should provide more context. A standalone error is not very helpful. You should include the exact steps and commands that you use to reproduce this error. You should also provide more context about what you are trying to do. Give us an example with details.

Comment: @Nmath now is it alright ?